# For a real, continuous function will the orbit of every point either tend towards a fixed point or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, fixed-points

"For a given real, continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and arbitrarily chosen $x_1$, and define $(x_n)$ by setting $x_{n+1} = f(x)$."

Am I correct in thinking that the orbit of any sequence constructed as above will either tend towards  a fixed point or will diverge? There are no real, continuous functions which cause a sequence to oscillate endlessly?

Comment: What about $f(x) = -x$, $x_1= 1$?

Comment: Ah yeah, of course. Thank you!

Comment: Also for an arbitrary “cycle” $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ you can find  a polynomial $p$ mapping $x_k$ to $x_{k+1}$ and $x_n$ to $x_1$.